Using GORM models in frontend of Wails app
I'm building a desktop app with Wails which writes to a local SQLite database.
I have the following model in my Go backend:
type FilmGroup struct {
    gorm.Model
    Films           []FilmRoll
    FilmOrder       FilmOrder
    Status          *string
    Description     *string
    Name            *string
}

I am using GORM as my ORM and the gorm.Model parameter inserts some standard table fields into my model.
I have a function that adds an object of this model into my database:
func AddFilmGroup(db *gorm.DB, filmGroup models.FilmGroup) error {
    if err := db.Create(&filmGroup).Error; err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not add film group: %w", err)
    }

    log.Printf("FilmGroup '%d' added successfully.\n", filmGroup.ID)
    return nil
}

And I have another function which is exposed to the frontend, that just calls the above function:
func (a *App) AddFilmGroupToDB(filmGroup models.FilmGroup) error {
    if a.database == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("database connection is not initialized")
    }

    err := db.AddFilmGroup(a.database, filmGroup)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to add film group: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

In my Svelte frontend, I am trying to add a function to call this Go function so it can add to the database:
    let newFilmGroup = {
        Name: "",
        Description: "",
        Status: "",
    };

    const submitFilmGroup = async () => {
        try {
            const filmGroup = {
                Name: newFilmGroup.Name,
                Description: newFilmGroup.Description,
                Status: newFilmGroup.Status
            };

            await AddFilmGroupToDB(filmGroup);

            closeAddFilmGroupModal();
        } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding film group:", error);
        }
    };

newFilmGroup will get populated with proper values by the UI through a form later, but for now just trying to test.
The issue is await AddFilmGroupToDB(filmGroup); is expecting the ID and other fields as well. The error I get is:
Argument of type '{ Name: string; Description: string; Status: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilmGroup'.
  Type '{ Name: string; Description: string; Status: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FilmGroup': ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt, and 3 more.js(2345)
const filmGroup: {
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    Status: string;
}

I'm not sure what I need to do to resolve this. This is just to create a new database entry for this model and it should only require the Name, Description, and Status fields to do so.
What change do I need to make to consume this function on my frontend properly?

Looks like mainly a type issue, could you have AddFilmGroupToDB take a struct that is a subset of FilmGroup only containing the required fields?

@brunnerh yeah seems like its a type issue. Is this the proper way to handle cases like this?

Depends, there are also ways of extracting or removing parts of existing types in TypeScript using e.g. Omit and Pick, but I would probably only use that if just one or two fields are affected (e.g. just removing an ID column).
